# How to manually choose where the data is displayed on a heatmap in Python with Matplotlib or Seaborn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have the following table in a pandas DataFrame, with the stats for a quarterback:

```
||    pass_type   |    WPA    ||
||----------------|---------- ||
|| deep - left    | -0.202351 ||
|| short - left   | 0.456855  ||
|| deep - middle  | -1.698436 ||
|| short - middle | 0.879427  ||
|| deep - right   | 0.378192  ||
|| short - right  | 1.448731  ||
```

I would like to display those stats in a heatmap, but I'd like to have the possibility to choose where each value is displayed. My goal is to "recreate" the field, with the first row being the short passes, the 2nd row being the long passes, the left column being the left passes, etc.
To be precise, what I'd like to get is:

```
deep  || -0.20 | -1.69  | 0.37  ||
short || 0.45  | 0.87   | 1.44  ||
---------------------------------
      ||  left | middle | right ||
```

I have been able to do it using plotly, by creating two lists, one with deep passes and the other with the short ones. But I would like to be able to do it using Seaborn or Matplotib, as I like their format options + it's easier to publish in a Jupyter Notebook on github.

Comment: *I have the following table* what do you use to store that table? list? numpy array? pandas dataframe?...

Comment: It's a pandas Dataframe. Sorry, forgot to mention it. I've edited my initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate the two parts with `str.split`:

```
plot_data = (df.join(df['pass_type'].str.split(' - ', expand=True))
               .pivot(index=0, columns=1, values='WPA')
            )
```

Then you would get `plot_data` as:

```
1          left    middle     right
0                                  
deep  -0.202351 -1.698436  0.378192
short  0.456855  0.879427  1.448731
```

which you can pass to `sns.heatmap`:

```
sns.heatmap(plot_data)
```

Output:

[image]